# Swift Mailer will not connect to SMTP host via CNAME

Tags: dns, swiftmailer

I am using a shared hosting provider (we'll call them hostco) simply to host email for a dozen domains. They put me on a server called (just an example) server1. So, to send email via Swift Mailer, in my script I specify the host as server1.hostco.com with a port of 465 and the specific username and password for the account I want to use.

Twice in the past I have switched hosting providers and had to update all of my scripts to reference the new host. Rather than doing that again, I just setup a new CNAME record on my domain that points mail.mydomain.com to server1.hostco.com. At first I thought it was great because Gmail is working perfectly using mail.mydomain.com to send email as me@mydomain.com. However, Swift Mailer will not connect.

So, why would Swift Mailer work when the host is server1.hostco.com but not when it is mail.mydomain.com even though that is just a CNAME that points to server1.hostco.com?

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 2181 section 10.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-10): "The domain name used as the value of a NS resource record, or part of the value of a MX resource record must not be an alias."

It appears that Swift Mailer is a bit more strictly standards-compliant.

Comment: You are right about the RFC, but I have never seen the delivery fail because of this. I would still check the logs if possible, I believe something else is the issue here.

Comment: The logs did not seem to provide any helpful info but this did get me thinking why one domain worked and one didn't when they resolve to the same IP.  I found [this](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/544#issuecomment-218408969).  I added those two lines (just to test) and it works.  So, the connection is being refused because the SSL cert is assigned to "hostco" not "mydomain."  Using the IP did not work either and now it makes sense why.

Comment: Final answer here.  Turns out it wasn't the RFC 2181 restriction of using an alias, just that Swift Mailer didn't like the mismatch between my domain and the domain on the SSL certificate.